# Spacing between subcaption and subfloat

Tags: spacing, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I'm currently using the subcaption package to set up figures with subfloats.
My current code is the following :

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{font=normalsize,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \caption{}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/Orientation_total_N1}
        \label{orientation_N1}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \caption{}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/Orientation_total_N2}
        \label{orientation_N2}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \caption{}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/Orientation_total_N3}
        \label{orientation_N3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \captionsetup{font=normalsize,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}    
    \caption{\textbf{Nothing} really interesting}
    \label{speed_orientation}
\end{figure}
```

Such that I have my figure with (a), (b) and (c) at the top left of my subfigures. However, I would like to reduce the vertical spacing between the markers (a), (b) and (c) form the empty subcaptions, and the top of my figure.

How do I do that ? I tried to use :

```
\captionsetup{font=normalsize,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,skip = 30pt}
```

but nothing changed, not matter the value I use after "skip".
More generally, how can I change all these length parameters in the subcaption package ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Use \captionsetup[sub]... or \captionsetup[subfigure]...

Comment: From the subcaption manual: The default settings for subcaptions are: "margin=0pt,size=smaller,labelformat=parens,labelsep=space,skip=6pt,list=false,hypcap=false". So to override the default `skip` settings use either `\usepackage[skip=...]{subcaption}` or `\captionsetup[sub]{skip=...}` (as John Kormylo already wrote).